# Diagrams for partial-ordered sets

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

The diagram below shows the relations between the subsets of a set with three elements {x,y,z}.

How can one in Tikz draw such diagrams?

[image]

Comment: Where is your solution attempt?

Comment: actually, I tried to do it but failed drastically. I can only do such diagrams in the case of trees

Comment: Not related to `circuitikz`, tag removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways. Here is a possibility with `tikz-cd`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={Triangle[open, length=2mm]}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw, ellipse, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=8mm}}]
& \{x,y,z\}\\
\{x,y\}\arrow{ur} & \{x,z\}\arrow{u} & \{y,z\}\arrow{ul}\\
\{x\}\arrow{u}\arrow{ur} & \{y\}\arrow{ul}\arrow{ur} & \{z\}\arrow{ul}\arrow{u}\\
& \varnothing\arrow{ul}\arrow{u}\arrow{ur}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!